# Check whether instance of a class exists, if not create an instance

Tags: php, class, autoload

I was wondering if it's possible to create a function and pass it a class name.  The function then checks if an instance of the class currently exists, if it does not it create an instance of the class. Furthermore if possible make that variable global and require it to be returned.   I realize that returning may be the only option.

```
 function ($class_name) {
      // Check if Exists
      // __autoload will automatically include the file
      // If it does not create a variable where the say '$people = new people();'
      $class_name = new $class_name();

      // Then if possible make this variable a globally accessible var. 
 }
```

Is this possible or am I being crazy?

Comment: So its suppose to create an empty class e.g. `class somename{}`?

Comment: No, the autoload is including the file with the class.

Comment: So you're asking to create an instance of the class if the class exists?

Comment: You sure you don't just want a [singleton](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Singleton_pattern)?

Comment: @case did u ever get a solution for this? having the same problem right now in javascript.

Answer (score 2):

`eval` is pretty much the only way to do this. It is very important you make sure this isn't provided by user input, like from `$_GET` or `$_POST` values.

```
function create_or_return($class_name) {
  if(! class_exists($class_name)) {
    eval("class $class_name { }");
    // put it in the global scope
    $GLOBALS[$class_name] = new $class_name;
  }
}

create_or_return("Hello");
var_dump($GLOBALS['Hello']);
/*
    class Hello#1 (0) {
    }
*/
```

You can't really make it globally accessible because PHP doesn't have a global object like javascript does. But you can't simply make a container holding the object.

Answer (score 1):

PHP has a function called class_exists($class_name), returns a bool.

http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.class-exists.php

Comment: Of course it does, that doesn't do the rest, or if the rest is even possible.

Comment: Of course... a simple if/else condition, if else, then create the class. However this is almost certainly a horrible idea and begging for exploitation. Just make a class and call it if need be.

Comment: @Iscariot I'd either return an instance of the class or hold a variable outside the function and initialize it to that class if it exists.

Comment: To create a class you need to use eval, why it's a bad idea `eval("class $class_name { function helloWorld() { echo 'hello world'; } }"); $theclass = new class_name(); echo $theclass->helloWorld();`

Answer (score 0):

Something along the lines of:

```
function some_fumction($class_name) {
    if(class_exists($class_name)) {
        return new $class_name;
    } else {
        throw new Exception("The class $class_name does not exist");
    }
}
```

Comment: This wouldn't work. The return would have to be set to $varname = function();  If it were already set this would kill the existing class.

Comment: Well you can't create an instance inside a function and use it outside that function. In that case there is no point in doing all of this, unless you are doing everything in the class constructor. I am not sure what you are trying to achieve in this case.

Comment: That's what I figured.  That's why I asked.  I want to know if its then able to set up that class and make it global.