# PHP: How to prevent multiple instances of extended class

Tags: php

I have a class that contains methods used globally, and am using them by extending the class:

App.php

```
final class App extends Core {

  // The app class handles routing and basically runs the show

}
```

Core.php

```
abstract class Core {

  public function __construct() { // Here we bring in other classes we use throughout the app
    $this->Db = new Db($this);
    $this->Mail = new Mail($this);
  }

  // Then we define multiple methods used throughout the app

  public function settings($type) {
    // You see this used by the model below
  }

}
```

index.php

```
$App = new App(); // This fires up the app and allows us to use everything in Core.php
```

Up until now, this is all great, because everything is handled throughout the site from within `$App`. However, within my MVC structure, the models need to pull data from the database, as well as retrieve other settings all contained in `Core`. We do not need the entire `$App` class to be used by the models, but we need `Core` to be.

MyModel.php

```
class MyModel extends Core { 

  public function welcome() {
    return 'Welcome to '.$this->settings('site_name');
  }

}
```

Once `MyModel.php` comes into play, the `Core` constructor is run a second time. How do I keep the `Core` constructor from being run twice?

Comment: This post might help: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23160509/check-whether-instance-of-a-class-exists-if-not-create-an-instance

Comment: Your App class should not access the db.. only the models should do that..

Comment: Also, take a look and read about Dependency Injection: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/130794/what-is-dependency-injection

Comment: As an App class, which can't has more the one instance, you could use Singleton pattern (it's just a tip, be careful with Singleton pattern, "great power comes great responsibility"). An App class shouldn't have access to the storage. There's a lot of patterns that can be used, a Register pattern, a Service Provider (which is a Register) or a Connection Manager could manage your services instances. Dependency Injection (as linked before) is the best way to share dependency without create without control.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use a static instance in the `core` class and reuse it.

```
abstract class Core {
  public static $instance; //create a static instance

  public function __construct() { // Here we bring in other classes we use throughout the app
    $this->Db = new Db($this);
    $this->Mail = new Mail($this);
    self::$instance = $this; // initialise the instance on load
  }

  // Then we define multiple methods used throughout the app

  public function settings($type) {
    // You see this used by the model below
  }

}
```

in the model class, use it like this

```
class MyModel extends Core { 

  public function welcome() {
    $_core = Core::instance; // get the present working instance
    return 'Welcome to '.$_core->settings('site_name');
  }

}
```

you can take a look at this [singleton reference](https://github.com/souparno/singleton-php-framework/blob/master/index.php)

 additionally you can check this answer [explain-ci-get-instance](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4740430/explain-ci-get-instance/31007257#31007257)

Comment: Your code has a few problems. First, it isn't a singleton because we can instantiate as many class as we want. Second, the use of a construct to create and storage his own instance is a bad pratice, because it's not its purpose. Third, you need test if it has a instance or if need be instantiated. And finally, CI has a really bad program design, as you linked a really bad coded class.